# Render partial JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs, react-table

I'm having some issue on rendering some JSON data into a React Table (which comes from the library react-table). Here is an exemple of a json I'm working with :

```
const translateditems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    colonne1: [
      {
        language: 'en',
        content: 'Column n°1'
      },
      {
        language: 'fr',
        content: 'Colonne n°1'
      }
    ],
    colonne2: [
      {
        language: 'en',
        content: 'Column n°2'
      },
      {
        language: 'fr',
        content: 'Colonne n°2'
      }
    ],
    dateCreated: '2018 - 02 - 01 30: 00: 00.000'
  }
]
```

For a chosen language, I need to only show one object of the translated texts of each column if needed. (In this example, the date does not need to be translated in any particular language)

Here is how I render my react-table :

```
constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: translateditems
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state
    const headers = []
    // I use all the name fields in the first json object as headers
    for (var key in Object.keys(data[0])) {
      headers.push(Object({
        'content': Object.keys(data[0])[key]
      }))
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={headers.map(header => {
            return ({
              Header: header.content,
              accessor: header.content
            })
          })
        }
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className='-striped -highlight'
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Do you have any clue on how to do this ?

**UPDATE**

Here's what I did to solve my problem :

```
return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={headers.map(header => {
            return ({
              Header: header.content,
              accessor: header.content,
              // I added a function to apply on my Cell
              Cell: row => (
                <div>{this.renderTranslatedItem(data, header.content, row.index)}</div>
              )
            })
          })
          }
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className='-striped -highlight'
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    )
```

And here's the function I made (assuming lang to be the language I want):

```
renderTranslatedItem (data, column, rowIndex) {
    // I check if the value is an array -> if it's not, then I return null
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(data[rowIndex][column]) !== '[object Array]') {
      return null;
    }
    for (var i in data[rowIndex][column]) {
      if (data[rowIndex][column][i].language === lang) {
        return data[rowIndex][column][i].content
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (var key in Object.keys(data[0])) {
    const headers = []
    // I use all the name fields in the first json object as headers
  headers.push(Object({
        'content': Object.keys(data[0])[key]
      }))
    }
```

In my example, I consider lang is passed through your props.
You have to replace it by:

```
const { lang } = this.props
const headers = Object.keys(data[0]).reduce(
    (acc, key)=> {
        return key!=='id' && key!=='dateCreated' && data[0][key][lang]
        ? { ...acc, [key] : data[0][key][lang] }
        : { ...acc, [key]:null }
},{})


//console.log(headers) will output this:
{
    colonne1:'colonne1',
    colonne2:'colonne2'
}
```

Comment: Your answer inspired the resolution of my problem, thank you !
However, you do rely on some column names (such as "id" or "dateCreated"), which doesn't make it dynamic. (If I change those names, then it cannot work anymore).